# How to prevent Mustache render some variable?

Tags: javascript, html, mustache

this is my html :

```
template = 
<table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; height: 15px; border-width: 1px; background-color: rgb(241, 196, 15);"><colgroup><col style="width: 33.2273%;"><col style="width: 33.2273%;"><col style="width: 33.2273%;"></colgroup>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="border-width: 1px; text-align: center;">Partner Name</td>
<td style="border-width: 1px; text-align: center;">Tenure Days</td>
<td style="border-width: 1px; text-align: center;">Maturity Date</td>
</tr>
{{#data.data}}<tr>
<td style="border-width: 1px; text-align: center;">{{PartnerName}}</td>
<td style="border-width: 1px; text-align: center;">{{TenureDays}}</td>
<td style="border-width: 1px; text-align: center;">{{MaturityDate}}</td>
</tr>{{/data.data}}
</tbody>
</table>
<p></p>
<p>Hello {{FunderName}}</p>
```

I was trying to render two times, the first one is render for the variable inside the `<table>` and the second is to render variable outside the `<table>` which is `{{FunderName}}}`.

But when I run the first render, the variable `{{FunderName}}` was replaced with empty string.

```
<table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; height: 15px; border-width: 1px; background-color: rgb(241, 196, 15);"><colgroup><col style="width: 33.2273%;"><col style="width: 33.2273%;"><col style="width: 33.2273%;"></colgroup>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="border-width: 1px; text-align: center;">Partner Name</td>
<td style="border-width: 1px; text-align: center;">Tenure Days</td>
<td style="border-width: 1px; text-align: center;">Maturity Date</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="border-width: 1px; text-align: center;">EPM</td>
<td style="border-width: 1px; text-align: center;">60</td>
<td style="border-width: 1px; text-align: center;">3 June 2022</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p></p>
<p>Hello </p>
```

How to prevent mustache to rendering the variable outside `<table>` ? or do you have another idea how to handle case like that ?

Please let me know if this information is still not enough to solve the problem

[[EDITED]]

This is the data source for rendering the html:

```
data = 
  Email: 'test@yopmail.com',
  PartnerName: 'dsadas',
  TenureDays: '43',
  MaturityDate: '22 Januari 2022',
  FunderName: 'andy',
  data: [
    {
      Email: 'test@yopmail.com',
      PartnerName: 'dsadas',
      TenureDays: '44',
      MaturityDate: '22 Januari 2022',
      FunderName: 'andy',
    },
    {
      Email: 'test@yopmail.com',
      PartnerName: 'akdasd',
      TenureDays: '32',
      MaturityDate: '12 Februari 2022',
      FunderName: 'andy',
    },
    {
      Email: 'test@yopmail.com',
      PartnerName: 'dasdasd',
      TenureDays: '22',
      MaturityDate: '10 Februari 2022',
      FunderName: 'andy',
    }
  ]
}
```

How can mustache can render variables inside the `<table>` and `{{FunderName}}` if the data was like that ?

I was using this code to render with mustache :

```
let renderTemplateContent = Mustache.render(template, { data });
```

It was work for rendering the variables inside `<table>` but no for `{{FunderName}}`

Comment: I’m not sure I understand. What do you mean by “first render”? It’s a template; it will render with whatever data you give it. If you don’t give it a `FunderName` it can’t render it. Are you trying to do a conditional render?

Comment: the data for rendering variable inside the ```<table>``` was object inside array. And the data for ```{{FunderName}} ``` was in the parent object. I will edited my post for adding the data source structure

Comment: … Pass all the data at once.

Comment: I was update my post, hope you can help with that

Comment: Just like you access the array with `data.data` you need to access the founder name with data.FunderName`.

Comment: im sorry forgot to add that ```FunderName``` data, how to pas all data at once ? Can you give example in snippet ?

Comment: The case is sometime the variable name and template html can be change, and can be more than 1 for variable outside the ```<table>```

Comment: Are you trying to do a conditional render?

Comment: yes i think, but i still doesn't know how conditional render in mustache look like

Comment: You’re already doing a [section](https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html#Sections) with `{{#data.data}}`, it’d be the same thing with `{{#data.FunderName}}`. Unrelated, but you might consider just passing `data` instead of nesting inside an object, `{ data }`, to avoid prefixing everything.